# Почему срабатывает счётчик?

Tags: javascript, angular2

Помогите пожалуйста понять почему в шаблоне срабатывает счётчик приходящих в дочерний компонент переменных?

[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-changedetection-prove-cansux)

Как видите, при вводе в поле input нового значения оно отправляется в дочерний компонент как Input-свойство. При это в дочернем компоненте каждый раз срабатывает инкремент счётчика.

component:

```
@Input()
public msg = '';

private _count = 0;

public renderCounter() {
  return ++this._count;
}
```

tpl:

```
<h3 *ngIf="msg">{{msg}}</h3>
<span>Render counter:  {{renderCounter()}}</span>
```

Мне не понятно почему происходит инкремент счётчика. Правильно ли я понимаю, что когда получением дочерним компонентом Input-значения засятавляет компонент полностью перерисовывать свой шаблон?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вы думали, что в Angular есть частичный рендеринг? Нет, `OnPush` - это всего лишь ограничение на то, когда будет запущен следующий механизм обнаружения изменений на представлении (view), которое маркировано, как `OnPush`.

Ссылка на `msg` не меняется просто так, это происходит благодаря обработчику событий `input`, который вешает директива `ngModel`. Так как Angular использует тотальный контроль над event loop'ом браузера - на любое асинхронное событие Angular запускает механизм обнаружения изменений, который рекурсивно пробегается по всему графу, используя алгоритм "поиск в глубину".

Алгоритм обнаружения изменений на какой-то вьюхе довольно таки прост абстрактно, но очень сложно реализован под капотом. Возьмем ваш компонент `onpush-value`. Когда происходит асинхронное событие - зона оповещает Angular о том, что "пожалуйста запусти механизм обнаружения изменений". Все что там происходит это:

```
tick() {
    if (this._runningTick) {
        throw new Error('ApplicationRef.tick is called recursively');
    }
    const scope = ApplicationRef._tickScope();
    try {
        this._runningTick = true;
        this._views.forEach((view) => view.detectChanges());
        if (this._enforceNoNewChanges) {
            this._views.forEach((view) => view.checkNoChanges());
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        // Attention: Don't rethrow as it could cancel subscriptions to Observables!
        this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => this._exceptionHandler.handleError(e));
    }
    finally {
        this._runningTick = false;
        wtfLeave(scope);
    }
}
```

В цикле проходит по всем вьюхам и вызывает метод `detectChanges`. `detectChanges` - это метод, который находится в прототипе класса `ViewRef_` (ссылка на вьюху). Что делает этот метод?

```
try {
    Services.checkAndUpdateView(this._view);
}
finally {
    if (fs.end) {
        fs.end();
    }
}
```

`checkAndUpdateView` в свою очередь вызывает синхронно большое количество других функций, все это происходит рекурсивно, по той причине, что вьюха может иметь ссылки на потомков, потомки в свою очередь на потомки, поэтому в цикле `while` потомок становится родителем.

Все, что делают те функции (вы можете открыть сурсы Angular и ознакомиться с ними детальнее) - это проверяют входные параметры (`input`), вызывают соответствующие методы жизненных циклов и перерисовывают компонент (благодаря классу `Renderer`). Но большинство этих функций возвращают `boolean` значение, поэтому Angular не просто проверяет входные свойства, Angular так же проверяет - маркирована ли вьюха, как `OnPush`:

```
if (compView.def.flags & 2 /* OnPush */) {
    compView.state |= 8 /* ChecksEnabled */;
}
```

Если же вьюха маркирована как `OnPush` и ссылки на входные параметры не изменились, то дело до `checkAndUpdateNode` просто не дойдет, поэтому вьюха просто скипнется, если же поменялась ссылка на любой входной параметр, то Angular отдает управление функциям `debugCheckAndUpdateNode` (в дев моде) либо `prodCheckAndUpdateNode` (в продакшн моде), которые перерисовывают полностью всю вьюху.

Comment: Это самый полный ответ, который я только мог представить)